# jdbc batch insert, how to split jobs?

Tags: java, jdbc

I split batched operation by 100 using `i` variable and this is my first *batch jdbc code*:

```
PreparedStatement oraclePs = oracleConn.prepareStatement("insert ...");
ResultSet sybaseRs = sybasePs.executeQuery();
int i = 1;
final int step = 100;
while (sybaseRs.next()) {
    oraclePs.setDate(1, sybaseRs.getDate("..."));
    ...
    oraclePs.addBatch();
    if (i++ % step == 0)
        oraclePs.executeBatch();
}
oraclePs.executeBatch();
oraclePs.close();
oracleConn.commit();
```

Is that right technique?

Is final out of loop `oraclePs.executeBatch();` correct if `i` end at 100 boundary?

How you select `step`? For Oracle I see that "Oracle SQL Developer" IDE import CSV with this step...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to only execute the final `executeBatch` if you know there is something left to process:

```
}
if(i % step != 0)
    oraclePs.executeBatch();

oraclePs.close();
oracleConn.commit();
```

Aside from that it looks good to me.

As for finding the value for `step`, I think it really depends on your use case and what the effect of your statement will be on the database.  You might want to try experimenting with different values to see how it affects performance.

Comment: I haven't worked with DBs for quite a while, is it customary to commit a connection after closing the prepared statement?

Comment: The connection commit and the prepared statement are independent so it doesn't matter which you do first.  Any ResultSets tied to a PreparedStatement will become unavailable once the statement closes though.  If you are calling this method multiple times you might want to consider caching the prepared statement and not closing it immediately since preparing a statement carries a significant overhead.